Indian expat in Japan looking for tourist visa to travel to China
I am from India, currently staying in Japan on an HSP visa. I'm looking for a China tourist visa. Do I need to apply for a visa from Japan using an agency? Or can I apply directly online without any agency? Or do I need to visit the Chinese embassy in Japan? Can someone help me here?

Looks like you can apply online

If possible avoid unnecessary agents, we see a lot of questions where an agent made mistakes that have a lot of negative impact.
